# Equation Subject to condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = 0 $, then prove that the following is true

$$ \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} = - \frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{abc} $$

Comment: maybe the first is equal to 1?

Comment: I made a mistake in the original formulation of the problem, it should have been the constraint is equal to 0

Comment: find c as a function of a and b from the first equation, plug it in the second one, and see what happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since $$\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c=0\Rightarrow \frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}=0,$$ we have $ab+bc+ca=0$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}-\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}&=-\frac{a^3}{abc}-\frac{b^3}{abc}-\frac{c^3}{abc}\\&=-\frac{a^2}{bc}-\frac{b^2}{ac}-\frac{c^2}{ab}\\&=-\frac{a^2}{-a(b+c)}-\frac{b^2}{-b(a+c)}-\frac{c^2}{-c(a+b)}\\&=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{a}{b+c} = \dfrac{a/bc}{(b+c)/bc} = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{bc}}{\dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{1}{c}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{bc}}{-\dfrac{1}{a}} = -\dfrac{a^2}{bc} = = -\dfrac{a^3}{abc}$$

$$\dfrac{b}{a+c} = \dfrac{b/ac}{(a+c)/ac} = \dfrac{\dfrac{b}{ac}}{\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{c}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{b}{ac}}{-\dfrac{1}{b}} = -\dfrac{b^2}{ac} = -\dfrac{b^3}{abc}$$

$$\dfrac{c}{a+b} = \dfrac{c/ab}{(a+b)/ab} = \dfrac{\dfrac{c}{ab}}{\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{b}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{c}{ab}}{-\dfrac{1}{c}} = -\dfrac{c^2}{ab} = -\dfrac{c^3}{abc}$$

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

$$
\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c=0\Rightarrow ab+bc+ca=0 \Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)=3abc+\sum a^2b=0
$$
So

$$
\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc+\sum a^2b}{-abc+3abc+\sum a^2b}=-\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Directly we have:

Since $\cfrac 1a+\cfrac 1b=-\cfrac 1c$ we have $\cfrac {a+b}{ab}=-\cfrac 1c$ or $-c=\cfrac {ab}{a+b}$ or $-\cfrac {c^3}{abc}=\cfrac c{a+b}$

Simply add the three forms for $a,b,c$.